# UIBarButtonItem - Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am having a problem with creating a nav button that would call `handleSearch` function. I receive a message `Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function`. Any help would be appreciated!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   // various code

   func setupNavBarButtons() {
       let searchImage = UIImage(named:"search_icon")
       let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch(sender:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [searchBarButtonItem]

    }

    func handleSearch(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print(123)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Is `handleSearch` inside another function?

Comment: it is inside viewDidLoad

Comment: I updated your question's code to make the issue clearer based on your comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`#selector` can only reference a top-level function, not a local function (one inside another function).

Simply move `handleSearch` out of `viewDidLoad` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: what if I don't  wanna move the #selector func out , in my case movie the func to the top-level would require too much work .

Comment: @aeid `#selector` only works with top-level functions. Period. If you don't want to move the function, you can't use a selector.

Comment: So there's no way to use a control that requires a selector if the selector must be inside a function? :(

Comment: @Glenn No. A selector passed in a typical target/selector use case must be a top-level function in the class.

Comment: @rmaddy Is there anything that can be used instead of #selector?